# String split in two lists

Tags: java, string, split

I would like to split a line which might look like this:

```
6:8.0 7:36.0 14:9.0 15:31.0 22:5.0 23:21.0 30:2.0 31:12.0 38:40.0 39:137.0 46:50.0 47:133.0 54:35.0 55:106.0 62:16.0
```

The first value is `x` the second `y`.
Now i would like to have as a result two Lists `ListX<Integer>` and `ListY<Double>`.

I have tried doing it char by char. Where you can search for ':' and then go back and front to get the number. But there must be a faster way. Especially regarding on the lenght of the string which can get really big. Do You have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: how about, using String.Split ... you could split at every whitespace, iterate through your result list, and split again using ':'. From there you can insert the seperate values in your two lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `String.split()`:

```
String test = "6:8.0 7:36.0 14:9.0 15:31.0 22:5.0 23:21.0 30:2.0 31:12.0 38:40.0 39:137.0 46:50.0 47:133.0 54:35.0 55:106.0 62:16.0";

String[] splitString1 = test.split(" ");
String[] splitString2 = null;

for(String a : splitString1)
{
    splitString2 = a.split(":");
    System.out.println(splitString2[0]);
    System.out.println(splitString2[1]);
    //push splitString2[0] to x
    //push splitString2[1] to y
}
```

Comment: @MichaelFaisst they are...I changed them right before you commented.

Comment: @JürgenK. no problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code which does what you are thinking to do

```
import java.util.*;

public class IntegerDoubleExtractor{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String test = "6:8.0 7:36.0 14:9.0 15:31.0 22:5.0 23:21.0 30:2.0 31:12.0 38:40.0 39:137.0 46:50.0 47:133.0 54:35.0 55:106.0 62:16.0";

        List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Double> y = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for(String xy : test.split(" ")) {
            String xys[] = xy.split(":");
            x.add(Integer.parseInt(xys[0]));
            y.add(Double.parseDouble(xys[1]));
        }
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and you won't need intermediate Strings or arrays in the process:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[:\\s]"));
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    listX.add(scanner.nextInt());
    listY.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```